# How to reparse a parsed string in C++ with Bison?

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am developing software that would allow you to replace words with others. The idea is that a character string will be parsed in a loop until there is nothing left to parse, but the problem is that when the parser returns a second time on a string, it does not read line breaks and especially certain words will not be parsed.

Here is my code:

**H5.y**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
typedef void* yyscan_t;
int lineNumber; // notre compteur de lignes
map <string,string> clayouts;
void yyerror ( char const *msg);
typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;

   void yyerror ( char const *msg);
    int yylex();
string initialdata;
string pdata="";
bool alway ;
%}
/* token definition */


%token STRING 
%token COMMAND
%token LPAREN RPAREN  LBRACE RBRACE
%token TXT
%union { char c; char str [0Xfff]; double real; int integer; }
%type<c> TXT;
%type<str> STRING COMMAND;
%start program
%%
program:value | command_call |txt | program program ;
value: STRING {pdata+='\"'+$1+'\"';cout<<"1";};
command_call : COMMAND LPAREN STRING  RPAREN   { 
    
    if(string($1)=="@field")
    {
         cout<<"define field :"<<$3;
         

    }
    else if(string($1)=="@include")
    {
        ifstream t;
        int length;
        char * buffer;
        t.open($3);     
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);    
        length = t.tellg();           
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);  
        buffer = new char[length];    
        t.read(buffer, length);       
        t.close(); 
        pdata+=buffer;
    }
    else if (string($1)=="@layout")
    {
        cout<<"define layout for field "<<$3;
    }
    else if (string($1)=="@repeat")
    {
        cout<<"reapeat instruction"<<$3;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"extend with : "<<$3;

         ifstream t;
        int length;
        char * buffer;
        t.open($3);     
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);    
        length = t.tellg();           
        t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);  
        buffer = new char[length];    
        t.read(buffer, length);       
        t.close(); 
       

    }
    alway=true;
     };//LPAREN RPAREN ;
txt: TXT {pdata+=$1;};

%%

void yyerror (const char *msg)
{
    cout<<msg;
}
```

**H5.l**

```
/*nodefault  bison-bridge*/
%{
extern int lineNumber; // definie dans prog.y, utilise par notre code pour \n
#include "h5parse.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
extern string initialdata;
extern string pdata;
extern bool alway ;
string val;
%}
/*reentrant bison-bridge*/
/* doesn’t need yywrap() */
 
%x strenv


i_command       @include
e_command       @extends
l_command       @layout
f_command       @field

command {i_command}|{e_command}|{l_command}|{f_command}

%%
"\""       { val.clear(); BEGIN(strenv); }
<strenv>"\""    { BEGIN(INITIAL);sprintf(yylval.str,"%s",val.c_str());return(STRING); }
<strenv><<EOF>> { BEGIN(INITIAL); sprintf(yylval.str,"%s",val.c_str());return(STRING); }
<strenv>.       { val+=yytext[0]; }
{command}       {sprintf(yylval.str,"%s",yytext);return (COMMAND);}
"("             { return LPAREN; }
")"             { return RPAREN; }
"{"             { return LBRACE; }
"}"             { return RBRACE; }
.               {yylval.c=yytext[0];return TXT; }
%%

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
ifstream t;
int length;
char * buffer;
if(argc>1)
{

t.open(argv[1]);     
t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);    
length = t.tellg();           
t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);  
buffer = new char[length];    // allocate memory for a buffer of appropriate dimension
t.read(buffer, length);       // read the whole file into the buffer
t.close();   
} 
initialdata=buffer;
do 
{
 alway=false;
pdata.clear();
 YY_BUFFER_STATE b =yy_scan_string(initialdata.c_str());
yyparse();

cout<<pdata;
initialdata=pdata; 
yy_flush_buffer(b);
 yy_switch_to_buffer(b);
yy_delete_buffer(b);

yylex_destroy();
BEGIN(INITIAL);
}while(alway==true);
cout<<pdata;


system("pause");
return(0);
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I thought the problem might be because the scanner was keeping the data. I used
yylex_destroy, yy_delete_buffer, yy_switch_buffer, etc... Please why do some strings vanish at the second parsing?

[image]
for more information about the project This is my github repository [my repository](https://github.com/ngdream/H5assembler)

Comment: Bison may not be the right tool for this. You may want to consider implementing the parser directly in code. With a help of decent parser support library, like `Boost.Spirit` it's not too difficult to do.

Comment: Could you create a minimal example showing the problem? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)